# why this in smarty can't work.?

Tags: php, smarty

in the index.php, i put this code in.

```
$smarty->assign('goods_commnet', get_comment_count());

function get_comment_count(){
    return 2;
}
```

then in the index.dwt. i put the output

```
{$goods_commnet}.
```

the smarty templae is ok.because when i instead the function to 2. the page can show 2.

the error tip is "can't get the  function get_comment_count() defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What will happen when You swich the order:

```
function get_comment_count(){
    return 2;
}

$smarty->assign('goods_commnet', get_comment_count());
```

Comment: it's ok. why i can't put the function under the assign. thank you

Comment: because PHP dosn't know it even exists when it executes $smart->assign line - this function is defined later

Comment: That is the case. As long as the function is in the same scope, it will be found. Otherwise you'd be able to declare the same function before and after the call and make the page work as long as the rest of the page is not run

Comment: You're right John, same scope in the same PHP file. It won't work if You are including a file with function definition after trying to call this function. (even it could still be at the same scope, other function body for example)